# WireGuard handshake did not complete after 5 second. It can't connect to server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, wireguard

I have digitalocean vds on Ubuntu 20.04LTS. To setup WireGuard I used this instruction https://www.vultr.com/docs/set-up-wireguard-vpn-on-ubuntu-20-04/ . When I try to connect with my android phone or iPad I usually saw that on log journal:[image]

Wireguard log:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17mJfn-3pL8blWptVu4oUC04vw3uCb1Sb/view?usp=sharing (I don't know what exactly need from this file. So i just leave it here.)

In this time on the server side:

> #wg show

```
interface: wg0
  public key: <pub key>
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: <pub key>
  endpoint: x.x.x.x:63360
  allowed ips: 172.26.5.67/32
  transfer: 2.46 KiB received, 1.53 KiB sent
```

> #systemctl status wg-quick@wg0

```
wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; disabled; vendor pr>
         Active: active (exited) since Fri 2022-09-02 10:43:40 UTC; 2h 5min ago
           Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
                 man:wg(8)
                 https://www.wireguard.com/
                 https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
                 https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
                 https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
        Process: 17323 ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up wg0 (code=exited, status=0/SU>
       Main PID: 17323 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I had got the connection with server but it was only once and never repeated again after disconnection.

There are server configurations:

> #sysctl -p

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

> #ufw status

Status: inactive

```
[Interface]
   
Address = 172.26.3.155/16
   
SaveConfig = true
   
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A
POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
   
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D
POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
   
ListenPort = 51820
   
PrivateKey = server_private_key


[Peer]

Blockquote

PublicKey = client_pub_key

AllowedIPs = 172.26.5.67/32

Endpoint = xx.xxx.xx.xx:63364 <--my phone ip:port (port always changed after reconnection)
```

There are client configurations:

```
[Interface]

Address = 172.26.5.67/16

DNS = 1.1.1.1

PrivateKey = client_p_key

    

[Peer]

PublicKey = serv_pub_key

AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0

Endpoint = xxx.xxx.x.x:51820 <- server ip:port ip wich I use to ssh connection
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Comment: Is your server directly on a public IP address, or behind a NAT router where you have to do additional settings?

Comment: I guess on public IP it's just a virtual machine on digitalocean server. Anyway how can i clarify which kind of IP I use?

Comment: [providing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/715912/edit) the results of these on server after WG is configured (you can obfuscate following rfc 1918, [rfc 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737.html) , but you must not change role between private and public IPs): `ip -br link; ip -4 -br address; ip route; ip rule` and  `nft list ruleset || iptables-save -c` (despite ufw inactive, there's WG to consider too) will help further. You get the idea. Also you shouldn't set "save" on server and shouldn't set a peer endpoint on server.